# Angular how to style routerLink

Tags: html, angular

I've got a lot of table rows in my app. Some are links, some are not. Here is an example of one that is:

```
<tr [routerLink]="['/invoices', invoice?.invoice.id || 0, 'sms']">
```

I want to style all tr's with a routerLink like this:

```
tr[routerLink] {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

But it does not work. What is the correct CSS here? thanks

Comment: Did you read this issue thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4532?

Comment: You probably have another issue, [because it works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfts4r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thx for the blitz, but your code has routerLink not [routerLink] and I believe the latter is correct - appreciate the attempt :)

Comment: @danday --I have updated my code.. have a look into that.

Comment: [Still works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfts4r?file=src%2Fstyles.css), just change the attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the compiled attribute `ng-reflect-router-link` : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfts4r?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

```
a[ng-reflect-router-link] {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}

tr[ng-reflect-router-link] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This only works in debug mode. The `ng-reflect-` attributes aren't added when building for production. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24730#issuecomment-401770950

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directive to add a class to every row with a `routerLink` attribute. Then style it in the css like normal.

```js
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'tr[routerLink]'
})
export class ClickableTableRowDirective {

  @HostBinding('class')
  className = 'clickable-table-row';

  constructor() {
        
  }
}
```

```css
.clickable-table-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<a [routerLink]='link' [ngClass]="{'router-link-active': true">{{name}}</a>
```

css:

```
.router-link-active {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Should work, but forces you to add a new attribute to every routed link.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem because of '**[ ]'** these brackets

so if you want to indentify which is the link and which is not then try below code

here's is example

```
<tr [routerLink]="['/invoices', invoice?.invoice.id || 0, 'sms']" routerLinkActive="active>
```

and in `style.css`

```
tr[routerLinkActive] {
    color: red;
 }
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8ynlj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) demo

this style only apply on those are links

Comment: He wants to style links, not active links.

Comment: My mistake,,I have updated the code ...its work for this situation

Comment: Why not simply `tr[routerLink]` ?

Comment: if the link is simply like <a routerLink-="/dummy"> then the css written by @danday74 will work but he want the routerlink with extra paramter so that time his style will not work

Comment: [See how to make it work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfts4r?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: Yeah now try with `[routerLinkActive]=" true ? 'active' : 'inactive'"`. The issue isn't with the attribute, it's with the syntax.

Comment: Yeah I checked, since you don't seem to understand, [here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eglckw?file=src/app/app.component.html) : it works with my syntax, it doesn't work with yours.